# How do I get 7 day rolling average based on the last 12 months?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have example of the data below:

| Date | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 3500.03 |
| 2020-01-01 | 3000.03 |
| 2020-01-01 | 3200.86 |
| 2020-01-01 | 4500.00 |
| 2020-02-01 | 2100.23 |
| 2020-02-01 | 1000.00 |
| 2020-03-01 | 2800.93 |
| etc | etc |

The data goes on like this covering a couple of years to present. My goal is to find the 7 day rolling average based on the previous 12 months. I have been trying to use a window function however I got wildly wrong results and I'm out of ideas despite research. If someone could help me out I'd appreciate it.

Edit, the exact code I tried is on another machine I currently do not have access to but I tried like the below:

```
SELECT 
DATE
,AMOUNT
,SUM(AMOUNT) OVER(PARTITION BY DATE ORDER BY DATE ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS WEEKAVG
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add in the query that demonstrates your best attempt at resolving this yourself, and then explain in what way it's failing to give the desired result. There are similar questions out there (let alone tutorials, etc) and we need to better understand your particular approach and why that approach is not working for you.

Comment: I have edited in something like I tried. I'm not sure what is causing the problem which is why I'm asking the question. It could be because each date has multiple rows but I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin this cat—especially if you care about maximum performance—but one approach is something like this:

```
WITH 
    DailyAmounts AS 
        (
        SELECT
            Date,
            SUM(Amount) AS DailyAmount
        FROM
            Table
        GROUP BY
            Date
        ) DailyAmounts

SELECT
    *,
    (
    SELECT 
        SUM(DailyAmount)
    FROM
        DailyAmounts DailyAmounts2
    WHERE
        Date BETWEEN 
            DATEADD(DAY, -6, DailyAmounts.Date)
            AND DailyAmounts.Date
    ) AS WeeklyAverageAmount
FROM
    DailyAmounts
;
```

In essence, create a daily amounts table via CTE; then, add a weekly average column and populate via subquery on the same CTE.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly. You need weekly avarage. You can use like this :

```
set datefirst 1;
WITH tempTable AS (SELECT datepart(week, yourDateColumn) as weekNr, amount from testTable)

Select weekNr, SUM(amount) from tempTable
group by weekNr
```

If you need daily avarage data query can be like that :

```
WITH tempTable AS (SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, yourDateColumn) AS weekDay, amount from testTable)
Select weekDay, SUM(amount) from tempTable
group by weekDay
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could use a window function here.

You just need to make sure that your data has a single row per day. You can do this by grouping first.

```sql
SELECT
  *,
  SUM(DailyAmount) OVER (ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS WeeklyAverageAmount
FROM (
    SELECT
      t.Date,
      SUM(t.Amount) AS DailyAmount
    FROM YourTable t
    GROUP BY
      t.Date
) ByDay;
```

Comment: This approach can fail if any dates happen to lack records in YourTable (e.g. a shop is occasionally closed and has no sales). In those cases, summing over the preceding six rows will include amounts from outside the trailing 7-day window.

Comment: Left-joining a calendar table (with it on the left side) will sort that out.

Comment: Indeed. It'd be helpful to throw that code into the answer, I think (for beginners and future visitors to this question).

Answer (score 0):

Just note that summing or adding amounts produces a TOTAL and not an AVERAGE.

Your sample data has multiple rows for only the first day of a MONTH, so I do not see how you can ever get a 7 day average from that.
(Unless you're using yyyy-dd-MM format, but I've never seen anybody do that.)

You should typically not be relying on the number of rows if you're looking for a specific date range - rather look at the dates themselves.

So, I am not really sure what you are looking for exactly, but maybe this can help you get on track:

```
-- prep data
select * 
into #tmp
from ( values 
    ('2020-01-01',  3500.03),
    ('2020-01-01',  3000.03),
    ('2020-01-01',  3200.86),
    ('2020-01-01',  4500.00),
    ('2020-02-01',  2100.23),
    ('2020-02-01',  1000.00),
    ('2020-03-01',  2800.93)
)t(date, amount)



-- output 
select 
    t.Date
    ,t.amount
    ,sum(amount) over (order by date) as running_total
    ,avg(amount) over (order by date) as running_avg
    ,tca.rolling_sevenday_total
    ,tca.rolling_sevenday_avg
from #tmp t
cross apply (
    select 
        sum(amount) as rolling_sevenday_total,
        avg(amount) as rolling_sevenday_avg
    from #tmp t7
    where 
        t7.date between dateadd(dd, -7, t.date) and t.date

) tca
```

| Date | amount | running_total | running_avg | rolling_sevenday_total | rolling_sevenday_avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 3500.03 | 14200.92 | 3550.230000 | 14200.92 | 3550.230000 |
| 2020-01-01 | 3000.03 | 14200.92 | 3550.230000 | 14200.92 | 3550.230000 |
| 2020-01-01 | 3200.86 | 14200.92 | 3550.230000 | 14200.92 | 3550.230000 |
| 2020-01-01 | 4500.00 | 14200.92 | 3550.230000 | 14200.92 | 3550.230000 |
| 2020-02-01 | 2100.23 | 17301.15 | 2883.525000 | 3100.23 | 1550.115000 |
| 2020-02-01 | 1000.00 | 17301.15 | 2883.525000 | 3100.23 | 1550.115000 |
| 2020-03-01 | 2800.93 | 20102.08 | 2871.725714 | 2800.93 | 2800.930000 |

And here's what it will look like if your data if your data is actually per day

```
-- prep data
select * 
into #tmp2
from ( values 
    ('2020-01-01',  3500.03),
    ('2020-01-02',  3000.03),
    ('2020-01-03',  3200.86),
    ('2020-01-04',  4500.00),
    ('2020-01-05',  4500.00),
    ('2020-01-06',  4500.00),
    ('2020-01-07',  4500.00),
    ('2020-02-01',  2100.23),
    ('2020-02-02',  1000.00),
    ('2020-02-03',  2800.93)
)t(date, amount)



-- output 
select 
    t.Date
    ,t.amount
    ,sum(amount) over (order by date) as running_total
    ,avg(amount) over (order by date) as running_avg
    ,tca.rolling_sevenday_total
    ,tca.rolling_sevenday_avg
from #tmp2 t
cross apply (
    select 
        sum(amount) as rolling_sevenday_total,
        avg(amount) as rolling_sevenday_avg
    from #tmp2 t7
    where 
        t7.date between dateadd(dd, -7, t.date) and t.date

) tca
```

| Date | amount | running_total | running_avg | rolling_sevenday_total | rolling_sevenday_avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 3500.03 | 3500.03 | 3500.030000 | 3500.03 | 3500.030000 |
| 2020-01-02 | 3000.03 | 6500.06 | 3250.030000 | 6500.06 | 3250.030000 |
| 2020-01-03 | 3200.86 | 9700.92 | 3233.640000 | 9700.92 | 3233.640000 |
| 2020-01-04 | 4500.00 | 14200.92 | 3550.230000 | 14200.92 | 3550.230000 |
| 2020-01-05 | 4500.00 | 18700.92 | 3740.184000 | 18700.92 | 3740.184000 |
| 2020-01-06 | 4500.00 | 23200.92 | 3866.820000 | 23200.92 | 3866.820000 |
| 2020-01-07 | 4500.00 | 27700.92 | 3957.274285 | 27700.92 | 3957.274285 |
| 2020-02-01 | 2100.23 | 29801.15 | 3725.143750 | 2100.23 | 2100.230000 |
| 2020-02-02 | 1000.00 | 30801.15 | 3422.350000 | 3100.23 | 1550.115000 |
| 2020-02-03 | 2800.93 | 33602.08 | 3360.208000 | 5901.16 | 1967.053333 |